# How to create API page using Python

Tags: javascript, python, json, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm a new to Vue js and Python. I have question here.

I have to create a simple page using Vue.js and python for backend. I use Heidi sql. My team asked me to create an API page that I've never do it before, and yea I searched on Internet and found that API page is used to create JSON response, so that I can call it from Vue.js using axios

So, i created file named api.py and in this file I made a code to connect with database and some query and it works fine when I run on my terminal. Ex: python api.py. My question is how do i create a json response from that so that the result will be in json and I can just axios.get('api.py') from my Vue js. Please explain details to me me as I'm a very very beginner for this. I show you my python file and example of vue js file that I will call the python file (api.py)

[api.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3w2W.png)
[vue file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKayv.png)

Comment: You need to use a Web Server like apache or nginx.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the Flask framework to create API.

Read this tutorial it might be helpful:
[link](https://codeburst.io/full-stack-single-page-application-with-vue-js-and-flask-b1e036315532)